# return php echo as error in html using ajax

Tags: php, ajax

```
        <?php
        $username=strip_tags($_POST['username']);
        $password=strip_tags($_POST['password']);


        $username=stripslashes($username);
        $password=stripslashes($password);

        $username=mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc,$username);
        $password=mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc,$password);

        $password=md5($password);

        $sql="SELECT * FROM mobile_users WHERE username='$username' LIMIT 1 ";
        $query=mysqli_query($dbc, $sql);
        $row=mysqli_fetch_array($query);

        //$expire=time() +60*60*24*30;
        //setcookie("");


        //}



        $id=$row['idmobile_users'];

        $db_password=$row['password'];
          $_SESSION['error'] = "could not connect";

        if($password==$db_password){
        $_SESSION['username']=$username;
        $_SESSION['id']=$id;
        $_SESSION['last_time']=time();

        header("Location: apply_now.php");

        }
        else {


            echo 'Invalid username or password';

        }


        }

        ?>
    <script>
$(function(){
$(document).on("click", ".button", function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
{       
//This will capture all the inputs from the form
var infom = $("#myform").serialize();
        //$("#showresult").addClass('loader');                
        $.ajax({            
            beforeSend: function() { },         
            type: "POST",
            url: "login.php",
            data:infom,          
            success: function(result){      
            //$("#showresult").removeClass('loader');
            $('#showresult').html(result);
            }
        });     
        e.preventDefault(); 
}
}); 
});
</script>
```

ok so i want it to place the error message from the php code where the id is in html, the id is in a span tag. Tried alot of ways but cant seem to get it working properly. I hope somone can help me resolve this issue. Thanks

Comment: Are the codes posted above from same page? Or PHP code is in another page?

Comment: @ krushio vida the php and html is on the same page but the ajax is in its own file

Comment: In your php page `$sql="SELECT * FROM mobile_users WHERE username='$username' LIMIT 1 ";` you are not checking the password? out curiosity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, Ajax code will not understand if the response from php page if it is an error or a success response, What you do just return the response but specify if it is an error or not in the PHP page.

It would be better if you separate your php page from your html page.

This should be in your **html page.**

```
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){
$(document).on("click", ".button", function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
{       
//This will capture all the inputs from the form
var infom = $("#myform").serialize();
        $("#showresult").addClass('loader');                
        $.ajax({            
            beforeSend: function() { },         
            type: "POST",
            url: "login.php",
            data:infom,          
            success: function(result){      
            $("#showresult").removeClass('loader');
            $('#showresult').html(result);
            }
        });     
        e.preventDefault(); 
}
}); 
});
</script>
    <style>
    .loader{
        background-image:url(http://loading.io/assets/img/default-loader.gif);
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
        background-position:center;
        height:100px;
        background-size: 30px;
    }
    </style>
<div id="showresult"></div>

<form id="myform">
<!--your inputs-->
<input name="username" type="text"><br>
<input name="password" type="text"><br>
<button class="button"> submit </button>
</form>
```

And this on your **php page**

```
   <?php

    //YOUR PHP CODES....

    header("Location: apply_now.php");
    // i would prefer something like
    echo ' welcome '.$username.' '; 
    echo "<script> window.location.href='apply_now.php';</script>";

    }
    else {


        echo 'Invalid username or password';

    }
    echo json_encode(array('error' => $error, 'message' => $message, 'redirect' => $redirect));


    ?>
```

Comment: ok i placed the php code in its own file but when i submit now i get a blank page.

Comment: @ShannaChambers Its like your Ajax code is not working correctly then. Should i give you another ajax code that will work for you?

Comment: @ShannaChambers I have provided the alternative

Comment: its not working it just stays on the page and not doing anything

Comment: @ShannaChambers if it stays on the page then most likely my html page works fine. your php page then has a problem. Should i give you a working approach for your php page?

Comment: my php page was working 100% i don't really want to change it because its working so wonderfully.

Comment: @ShannaChambers Change this on your php page `header("Location: apply_now.php");` to `echo ' welcome '.$username.' '; 
echo "<script> window.location.href='apply_now.php';</script>"; `

Comment: dont know but its not doing any thing it just stay on the same page when i click the submit button

Comment: @ShannaChambers For testing  lets do this. Clear everything in your HTML page Then copy my code only for html  as it is and try to see if anything happens. change this part in the ajax code to reflect your php page `... url: "login.php",`

Comment: i did that but nothing works it just stays there doing nothing sorry. actually it tries to load the gif img when click but that's all it doesn't give me the error message and if i type in the correct user name and password it just do the same thing again.

Comment: Also on your php page remove everything and add this for testing. Just try  `<?php
    $username=$_POST['username'];
    $password=$_POST['password'];
 
 echo "Username: $username"; 
 echo "<br>and<br>";
 echo "Password: $password"; 

?> ` Just try for testing

Comment: ok it works!! but why wont mine work? i need my php to work its so robust

Comment: are you there? I need your help.

Comment: UP to there i believe i have answered your question. Now the problem is in your php code for login in the person. The ajax part i believe it is solved . remove this `echo json_encode(array('error' => $error, 'message' => $message, 'redirect' => $redirect)); }` we no longer need it on the php page. Try n see if it works

Comment: i did that along time ago

Comment: Replace to this `$query=mysqli_query($dbcl) or die(mysqli_error($dbc));` to the query. then Add this at the top of page   `if (!isset($_SESSION)) { session_start();}`

Comment: ok could you just copy my code and try if it works on yours its at the top of the page

Comment: its working now i just removed the if(isset($_POST['login'])

Answer (score 0):

I dont understand exactly what you mean but when i look at the code could it be that youre page is just refreshing afther the submit? If im correct the form will reload the page on a submit if you dont use e.preventDefault(). If it is reloading just include the prevent default, the rest of youre code looks ok

Comment: could you check through the code again its not working even after i use the e.preventDefault();

Comment: Do you see the console log afther submitting it?

Comment: its not showing on the html page nothing or should i go into browser inspector to see it

Comment: If you are using chrome you could use the developer tools by hitting f12 otherwise just change it to alert(response);

Comment: its responding the entire html page except the section with the php code.

Comment: You are you using it on the same page i think thats the problem take the lgoic part to a seperste file that you are calling in youre ajax request. Then return it from there back to youre ajax request. The problem now is that youre request contains html and it isnt just clean json